# Receiving UDP packets from Wireless IMU application in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, udp, gyroscope

I have a project where I have a [wireless IMU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwiener.wimu&hl=en_SG) application on my android phone. Based on the app description, it sends out accel/gyro data in csv format over UDP to a target IP address and port.

Currently I am trying to code a UDPListener in Unity that receives this data.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class UDPReceiver1 : MonoBehaviour
{
Thread udpListeningThread;
public int portNumberReceive;
UdpClient receivingUdpClient;
string[] delimiters = { ", ", "," };
string[] data;

void Start()
{
    initListenerThread();
}

void initListenerThread()
{
    Debug.Log("Started on : " + portNumberReceive.ToString());
    udpListeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UdpListener));

    // Run in background
    udpListeningThread.IsBackground = true;
    udpListeningThread.Start();
}

public void UdpListener()
{
    receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(portNumberReceive);

    while (true)
    {
        //Listening 
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
            byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

            if (receiveBytes != null)
            {
                string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);
                Debug.Log("Message Received" + returnData.ToString());
                Debug.Log("Address IP Sender" + RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString());
                Debug.Log("Port Number Sender" + RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());

                data = returnData.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Debug.Log(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    if (udpListeningThread != null && udpListeningThread.IsAlive)
    {
        udpListeningThread.Abort();
    }

    receivingUdpClient.Close();
}
}
```

As of now this code does not work at all, and I have been very perplexed as to why it isnt working. Many forums seem to follow the same structure and the code seems logical.

When I tested the connection, what i did was to attach this script to a gameobject, set an arbitrary port number, e.g. "12345", and Play. Meanwhile I ran the application on my android phone, with the target IP address being the computer's Ip address and the target port number being the same port number I used earlier.

I would really appreciate it if any kind soul can help, as I have been stuck here for close to 2 weeks;(

Comment: did you add INTERNET permissions to your android manifest?

Comment: @zambari Is that done in the wireless IMU application? I dun think I have permissions to change the manifest for that app. I did however already add an inbound rule on a UDP port that I wanna use but it still did not work.

Anyone tried to copy paste my code and managed to get the data flowing from the phone to the computer?

Comment: oh, sorry, my fault, I misread your question

Comment: another thing to suggest is disabling your Windows Firewall, I think default rules prevent inbound traffic

Comment: @zambari Hey man, is there a specific setting for Windows Firewall that i can disable without disabling the whole thing?